# How to get an overall coverage value from go test -cover?

Tags: go, code-coverage

Using the `-cover` option of `go test`, eg

```
go test ./... -covermode=atomic -coverprofile coverage.out
```

`coverage.out` contains lots of output for each file, but I want a single number for overall coverage (which can be used to pass/fail coverage).

I found a reasonable (although erroneous!) script solution in [this article](https://eleni.blog/2021/01/10/test-coverage-in-go-working-with-packages-and-sub-packages/#7):

```
cat coverage.out | \
awk 'BEGIN {cov=0; stat=0;} \
    $3!="" { cov+=($3==1?$2:0); stat+=$2; } \
    END {printf("Total coverage: %.2f%% of statements\n", (cov/stat)*100);}'
```

but is there a non-script, `go` way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We us `gotestsum` for this purpose. It is a replacement for `go test` with additional features, like outputting in JUnit XML format.

https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum

The disadvantage of using a third party tool like this is, that your developers and CI need to have it installed.

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but this doesn't really answer the question. Given the option of the tiny script or importing a GitHub project, the script wins IMHO.

Comment: No problem @Bohemian. I get that a script is preferable. I just provided _a_ solution. Maybe others might prefer it. In the end the constraints you provided ("but is there a non-script, go way to do this?") let me to believe that you are not looking for a script. And `gotestsum` is written in Go etc. But anyway.

Comment: "The disadvantage of using a third party tool like this is, that your developers and CI need to have it installed."

The way I get around this is to us a Makefile and use a `go run` command to run the package without installing. E.g.

`go run gotest.tools/gotestsum@latest -- -coverprofile=coverage/coverage.out ./...`

Comment: @Lewsmith That is a very interesting comment. I did not know about this possibility. Since we also use a `Makefile` I will definitely give this a try. Thank you.